# Flow of execution in Httpwebrequest POST in Windows hone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

If I have this code in Windows Phone 8, for instance

```
    string __retS = null;

    private String postRequest(String url, String postData)
    {
        byte[]byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        HttpWebRequest request = null;

            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

                // start the asynchronous operation
                request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

            } // end try
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return __retS;
        }
```

I put a breakpoint on this line `request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);`. I expected that execution will jump to my `GetRequestStreamCallback` method but it doesn't. It rather goes on to execute the return statement hence a null value is always returned.

Is that how its supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that how its supposed to go?

Yes. When the work is done it will invoke the callback function you passed.  See ["Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).  Starting with .Net 4.5 / c# 5.0,  you can use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) which can help to write async codes simpler.

```
var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
//...do some work using that stream
```

Comment: So, will using async/await hold on the `(request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);)` until `GetRequestStreamCallback` finishes executing?

Comment: @NiiLaryea No you won't use that Begin___ methods. Just one line as in my answer. Then `stream` is *(somehow magically :) )* ready

Comment: Are you using VS2012?

Comment: Yep, for Windows Phone.

Comment: @NiiLaryea And you are targeting `.Net 4.5` ?

Comment: I am. Does it matter that it's Express Edition?

Comment: @NiiLaryea No, I use it too :)

Comment: @NiiLaryea People use it happly. See [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/news/windows-8---windows-phone-code-sharing-httpwebrequest-getresponseasync)

Answer (score 0):

The callback is executed asynchronously, that means the code is continued after the asynchronous method is assigned. (`request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);`)
When the `WebRequest` is finished, the `GetRequestStreamCallback` is executed.
Because the UI thread would be blocked if this request was synchronous the windows phone sdk only serves an asynchronous one.

Comment: How then do I structure my code so that the async method `GetRequestStreamCallback` is executed before the `WebRequest` is finished?

Comment: With the await keyword before the method (as @I4V said). This will make the asynchronous request to an synchronous and waits for the callback.

Comment: @user2737037 No no. Your edited code will cause a deadlock. Don't block UI thread with `WaitOne`. I'll vote it down if you don't correct it.

Comment: @user2737037 But now, it is nonsense. `End__` methods should be called in callback methods. As you can see, It is not easy to get a `sync-like` effects using async methods. As a side note, you may want to read something about `TaskCompletionSource` which is commonly used in such cases.